# NSInteger versus int

Tags: nsinteger

What would be the reason to use an NSInteger vs an int in iPhone programming? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `NSInteger` is just a typedef with the following definition:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
  typedef long NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
  typedef int NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

As the typedef is defined differently basing on the platform, you can keep using `NSInteger` independently from the platform.